# Sharepoint workflows - create a new item on a seperate site list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

just wondering if it is possible to do the following using sharepoint designer. Ok say i have to separate sites on sharepoint; Site 1 and Site 2. Site 1 contains a list named "Employees" and Site 2 contains list named  "New Employees". Both list contain the columns "firstname", "lastname". Could i run a workflow on the "Employees" list on Site 1 that would run when a new item is added to this list, the workflow when run would create a new item on the "New Employees" list on Site 2. So for example if you added an new employee "john Smith" to the "employees" list on site 1, the workflow would then create a new item "john Smith" on the "new hires" list on site 2.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you should utilise the "Call To HTTP service actions" to create the item cross sites. Next to that you shoould give the Workflow "App trust"

for the app trust see the following site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx